# Can't properly save QChartView as image when using QLineSeries with openGL on

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qchart

i am trying to create an application which can plot large data sets (so using of OpenGl is important to me). I use `QChartView`, `QChart` and `QLineSeries`. Also for `QLineSeries` i turn using openGL on. But when i'm trying to save chart as an image i get plot without data. I know that when `QLineSeries` using openGL it creates a `QOpenGLWidget` on top of the chart plot area, but i don't know ho to access it.

**So a question is**: how to save a chart as an image with drawn lines?

Some images:

What i want (Plot without using openGL):

[image: Plot without using openGL]

What i get (Plot with openGL):

[image: Plot with openGL]

Here is an example of code:

MainWindow constructor:

```
chartView = new QChartView(generate_sin_chart(), ui->centralWidget);
ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(chartView);
```

generate_sin_chart():

```
QLineSeries *series = new QLineSeries();
series->setUseOpenGL(true); //this line cause a problem

constexpr double PI = 3.14159265359;
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    double temp = i*PI/6;
    series->append(temp, sin(temp));
}

QChart *chart = new QChart();
chart->legend()->hide();
chart->addSeries(series);
chart->createDefaultAxes();
chart->setTitle("Simple line chart example");

return chart;
```

Function for saving:

```
QString filename = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save file"), "", tr("Images (*.png)"));
QPixmap p = chartView->grab();
p.save(filename, "PNG");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.10/qabstractseries.html#useOpenGL-prop):

> **useOpenGL : bool**
>
> Specifies whether or not drawing the series is accelerated by using OpenGL.
>
> Acceleration using OpenGL is supported only for QLineSeries and QScatterSeries. A line series used as an edge series for QAreaSeries cannot use OpenGL acceleration. When a chart contains any series that are drawn with OpenGL, a transparent QOpenGLWidget is created on top of the chart plot area. The accelerated series are not drawn on the underlying QGraphicsView, but are instead drawn on the created QOpenGLWidget.
>
> [...]

So when you use `grab()` only take a picture of the `QChartView`, the solution is to find the `QOpenGLWidget` object and record its image on top of the `QChartView` image, the following code does it:

```
QPixmap p = chartView->grab();
QOpenGLWidget *glWidget  = chartView->findChild<QOpenGLWidget*>();
if(glWidget){
    QPainter painter(&p);
    QPoint d = glWidget->mapToGlobal(QPoint())-chartView.mapToGlobal(QPoint());
    painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceAtop);
    painter.drawImage(d, glWidget->grabFramebuffer());
    painter.end();
}
p.save("test", "PNG");
```

As you should use `QOpenGLWidget` you must add `QT += opengl` to your .pro

A complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/48139716)

Answer (score 1):

I met exactly the same problem. You can solve it by disabling the animations for QChart.