# How to save QChart as image?

Tags: qt, qchart

I have chart with differrent series. I need to save current ChartView as image. [image] I tried to do it as:

```
QPixmap p(this->size());
QImage* image= new QImage;
QPainter *painter= new QPainter(this);
chartView->render(painter);
if(!image->save("test.png"))
    qDebug()<<"ERROR";
```

I have next error: "QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1"

Comment: You're trying to paint on the widget but want on the image - pass the created pixmap to your painter. The image is unsed and not needed.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/q/48139716/4149835

Answer (score 2):

you can use grab and save functions

grap image and than save it

```
chartWidget.grab().save("test2.png")
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the Low Quality Queue. Code only answers are not considered good answers, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are less useful to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / better than existing answers.